# R : Help needed for linear regression in time series. The date column is of the format month-year

Tags: r, time-series

Time series Date Sales 1 Jan-95 1664.81 2 Feb-95 2397.53 3 Mar-95 2840.71 4 Apr-95 3547.29 5 May-95 3752.96 6 Jun-95 3714.74 7 Jul-95 4349.61 8 Aug-95 3566.34 9 Sep-95 5021.82

This is the time series code :
t<-ts(data$Sales,frequency=12,start=c(1995,1))

This is the task I have to perform : Fit a linear trend model with additive seasonality (Model A) and exponential trend model with multiplicative seasonality (Model B). Consider January as the reference group for each model.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Programmerinthering! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

As r2evans has said, it's difficult/impossible to solve conclusively without seeing the timeseries you created, as the frequency would determine the answer. But here is an answer which should work regardless of the frequency:

```
freq <- 12

# create a timeseries object
data <- ts(data = 1:1000, start = c(2010, 1), frequency = freq)

# seq() in this case creates a sequence of numbers from 1 to the length of the data, with a step of freq
data[seq(1, length(data), freq)]
```

Comment: Thank you for response.
Time series 
Date     Sales
1  Jan-95   1664.81
2  Feb-95   2397.53
3  Mar-95   2840.71
4  Apr-95   3547.29
5  May-95   3752.96
6  Jun-95   3714.74
7  Jul-95   4349.61
8  Aug-95   3566.34
9  Sep-95   5021.82
This is the time series code : t<-ts(data$Sales,frequency=12,start=c(1995,1))

This is the task I have to perform :

Fit a linear trend model with additive seasonality (Model A) and exponential trend model
with multiplicative seasonality (Model B). Consider January as the reference group for
each model.

Comment: @Programmerinthering add it to your question, along with dput(data)